# How to install a custom Ubuntu Touch Kernel on the Nexus 10

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-touch, debian, nexus-10

I've just installed the latest version of Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 10 tablet,but it does not fit my needs. Instead of it,I would like to install a minimal version of Ubuntu or Debian running with the kernel 3.13. I want to do that for several reasons :

1) My nexus 10 has not so much space inside of it

2) I don't want unity and a lot of other packages contained inside the current Ubuntu Touch release

3) I want to start to learn how things works from the beginning

4) I want to install a lighter desktop environment such as lxde or xfce

5) I want to try to use X11 instead of MIR

6) the kernel 3.13 works good for the arm Chromebook,why it should not work for the nexus 10,also ? ...(read here :)

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/

so,can you help me ? I would like to know how can I do that,do you have some tutorial so I can learn ? thanks.